# logical check if the vector values at the same precesion or not

Tags: r

I want to check last two values of my vectors are in the same precision or not without knowing their values.

For example, if last two vectors `0.0194` and `0.0198` return `TRUE`. 
that means these numbers are in (0.01 order 10^-2). ! for other example the number could be   `0.00014` and `0.00012` so their precision is still around the same the function should return also `TRUE`

```
x<- c(0.817104, 0.241665, 0.040581, 0.022903, 0.019478, 0.019846)
```

I tried `all.equal` but it returned `FALSE`
I need a logical function something like `all.equal`

```
  isTRUE(all.equal(tail(x,2)[1],tail(x,2)[2]))

 # [1] FALSE
```

Is there any function can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply

```
diff(tail(x,2)) < 0.01
```

or even better use `abs`:

```
abs(diff(tail(x,2))) < 0.01
```

Comment: thanks for reply. What if you don't know last two item in the 0.01 order say if they are in 0.0001 order. Something like universal function that I needed.

Comment: What do you mean universal? You can parametrize the `0.01`if that's what you're asking?

Comment: universal means, the function automatically can check this logical thing that returns `TRUE`. Now because of I put reprocible example we can know their order. But what if we dont know their order.

Comment: Not sure i understand,  but you can write the above in simple function as `last.two.within.precision <- function(v,precision) { return abs(diff(tail(v,2))) < precision }`. This will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Sorry, still dont understand what you mean by "what if we don't know their order" ... Even `all.equal` uses precision (tolerance) - see `?all.equal`

Comment: Ok you are right. I know `all.equal` has tolerence property. Maybe I'm looking for something different. I try to say without knowing their precision of these two number Could it be possible to know their precision is in the same order or not?